# Peek ahead a \vbox: \vsplit and reassemble again?

Tags: boxes

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement a *peek* method to inspect the head of a `\vbox` without changing the content of the `\vbox`. It could be done by brute force using a `\copy` of the original `\vbox`, but I'm looking for a not so brutal method.

With the following code, a `\bigbox` is constructed, its head split of as `\partbox`, and finally all is reassembled again as `\bigbox`. `\testmybox` serves for showing the boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\testmybox#1{%
  \par%
  {\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\copy#1}}\par%
  \edef\myboxheight{\the\dimexpr\ht#1+\dp#1\relax}%
  Total height: \myboxheight%
}

\begin{document}

\newbox\bigbox
\newbox\partbox

\setbox\bigbox=\vbox{\hsize 11cm%
  \footnotesize\blindtext[1]}

\textbf{Original box}\par
\testmybox\bigbox

%\splittopskip=0pt
%\splitmaxdepth=0pt

\setbox\partbox=\vsplit\bigbox to 45pt%

\textbf{Splitted box:}\par
\testmybox\partbox

\textbf{Rest:}\par
\testmybox\bigbox

\setbox\bigbox=\vbox%
{%
  \unvbox\partbox
  \unvbox\bigbox
}

\textbf{Reassembled box:}
\testmybox\bigbox

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that the reassembled box is not identical to the original box. Here, there is too much space between the two parts. This space depends on the `\splittopskip` value, but I don't know how to set this value such that it works with all thinkable situations.

Is it possible to reassemble the original box without deviation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since nobody answered or commented this question, I thought there was no answer. But then I found `\splitdiscards` and `\savingvdiscards` from e-TeX which seem to be exactly the missing commands. With it, the answer seems to be stupidly easy - would have saved my many hours if I knewed this before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\def\testmybox#1{%
  \par%
  {\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\copy#1}}\par%
  \edef\myboxheight{\the\dimexpr\ht#1+\dp#1\relax}%
  Total height: \myboxheight%
}

\begin{document}

\newbox\bigbox
\newbox\partbox

\setbox\bigbox=\vbox{\hsize 11cm%
  \footnotesize\blindtext[1]}

\textbf{Original box}\par
\testmybox\bigbox

\splittopskip=0pt
%\splitmaxdepth=0pt
\savingvdiscards=1
\setbox\partbox=\vsplit\bigbox to 45pt%

\textbf{Splitted box:}\par
\testmybox\partbox

\textbf{Rest:}\par
\testmybox\bigbox

\setbox\bigbox=\vbox%
{%
  \unvbox\partbox%
  \splitdiscards%
  \unvbox\bigbox%
}

\textbf{Reassembled box:}
\testmybox\bigbox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still believe that `\setbox\tempbox=\copy\bigbox` is cleaner if you just want to access `\bigbox` for measuring but not touching it.

Comment: @egreg but less efficient memory-wise, which may occasionally matter.

Comment: @egreg I use this for madly large boxes where a copy *really* costs memory.